# Android Socket.IO

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io, serversocket

I am getting Using Socket.IO library on Android to connect to Node.js server.

Sometimes I face failed xhr poll error on certain devices. Happens only sometimes and I am not able to exactly figure out what causes this.

Initialising of socket

```
if (socket == null) {
        IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
        options.forceNew = true;
        options.reconnection = true;
        options.reconnectionAttempts = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        options.reconnectionDelay = 1000;
        try {
            socket = IO.socket(url, options);
            addSocketListener();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 public static SocketListener getInstance(String id, LocationListener listener){
    if(socketListener == null){
        socketListener = new SocketListener(id, listener);
    }
    return socketListener;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a `stacktrace` of the error?

Comment: could be something wrong with your server